# Whitespace causes problem in BigQuery with Python

Tags: python, sql, caching, google-bigquery, whitespace

I have got the following Python code to retrieve a BigQuery dataset. Then I execute two queries **working_query** and **bad_query** on a Jupyter [Notebook on kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/calyxus/bigquery-problem/edit). 
The only difference is an added whitespace on line 3 after 
`` ...posts_questions` as q `` which makes the bad_query fail with the message

`Query exceeded limit for bytes billed: 10000000000. 24460132352 or higher required.`

I know that cost controls are enabled but do not see how this could be the issue here.
How can I avoid such traps in the future and can someone explain the problem?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = client.dataset("stackoverflow", project="bigquery-public-data")
dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_ref)

safe_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(maximum_bytes_billed=10**10)

answers_query_job = client.query(working_query, job_config=safe_config) 
answers_query_job.to_dataframe()
```

```
working_query = """
                SELECT a.id, a.body, a.owner_user_id
                FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` AS a
                INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` AS q
                    ON q.id = a.parent_id
                WHERE q.tags LIKE '%bigquery%'
                """
```

```
bad_query = """
                SELECT a.id, a.body, a.owner_user_id
                FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` AS a
                INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` AS q 
                    ON q.id = a.parent_id
                WHERE q.tags LIKE '%bigquery%'
                """
```

*UPDATE:*

It was a caching problem as the working_query was run before activating cost control. That way it could retrieve data from cache even with cost control enabled. 
The queries have to be absolutely identical to share the cache so even added whitespace can prevent that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have cost controls enabled: [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#limit_query_costs_by_restricting_the_number_of_bytes_billed)

This error means that your query was about to scan more bytes than the limit set in "Maximum Bytes Billed".

Can you reliably reproduce this error? Doesn't look like whitespace in the query would have anything to do with cost cont in BigQueryrols.. Maybe just a coincidence when either data was larger, or cost controls were introduced.

Edit: Alexandre is right in his answer - "good query" succeeds because it takes results from the cache. Just retried with (note use_query_cache, not UseQueryCache in the comment thread above)

```
safe_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(maximum_bytes_billed=10**10, use_query_cache=False)
```

And got the same error for the good query. Also, you can check cache_hit in the result job to see if response was taken from the cache. Whenever query succeeds, it's equal to true:

```
print("Cache hit: ")
print(answers_query_job.cache_hit)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am aware that cost controls are enabled, the question is why a whitespace can trigger this behaviour? Here is a link to my notebook and yes it is reproducible see this [kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/calyxus/bigquery-problem/edit)

Comment: This is indeed an issue with query cache Alexandre mentioned in his response - I just retried your notebook with use_query_cache=False, and I see the same error

Comment: Updated the response, unfortunately I can't comment on your comment thread above. Alexandre Moraes was on the right track, just should have used use_query_cache=True instead of UseQueryCache. See documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#python

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong, it seems i did not clearly state the problem. You just have to change the query in answers_query_job to "working_query" in my notebook and there is no error, no matter if you disable cache or not. Fill in bad_query and it throws an error.

Comment: I get that. The way you enable cache was wrong. When I set use_query_cache=True, both "working_query" and "bad_query" return the same error. Previously there was UseQueryCache=True, which is incorrect parameter name.

Comment: See this notebook: working_query no longer works when cache is disabled: https://www.kaggle.com/alexeyk/bigquery-problem

Comment: You are right i used the wrong command there to disable cache. Here is my point, let us put `use_query_cache=True` and then run both queries. At least for me working_query always succeeds and bad_query not. Now can you explain that and what it has to do with cache?

Comment: Yes. working_query costs nothing, because it just loads data from the cache. Hence it's not affected by cost controls, whatever you set there. Because it's free. bad_query always fails because of cost controls. If, for the sake of experiment, you could run bad_query with cost constrols off, it would also have cached value, and would likewise start succeeding if retried. To quote documentation: "To retrieve data from the cache, the duplicate query text must be exactly the same as the original query.". So even adding spaces would cause the cache to be invalidated.

Comment: You're absolutely right, just did the experiment and it worked out as you said. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have performed some tests using both of your queries and they were executed in the same way.

First, I must point that the **query()** method receives a string and *job_config* is used to configure the job. In addition, the documentation does not mention any issues related to extra spaces in side your *query string*, [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/_modules/google/cloud/bigquery/client.html#Client.query).

Furthermore, if you navigate to the BigQuery UI, copy and paste one query at a time and execute it, you will see, under ***Job Information***, that both queries will process roughly 23Gb of data and the same amount of data will be the  ***bytes billed***. Therefore, if your set `bigquery.QueryJobConfig(maximum_bytes_billed=23000000000)` and *omit the `to_dataframe()` method*, both queries you stated above will run perfectly.

**UPDATE**:

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results), by default you have `use_query_cache` set to true, which means if you run the same query it will retrieve the results from a previous one. For this reason, no bytes will be processed. If you ran your query previously without the `maximum_bytes_billed` set. Then you run the same query with a maximum amount, the query will run even though, it processed more than what you set now.

In your case, I used a Python 3 Notebook from the AI Platform and a .py file within the Shell to run the following codes.

First code,

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas

client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = client.dataset("stackoverflow", project="bigquery-public-data")
dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_ref)

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(maximum_bytes_billed=10**10)
job_config.use_query_cache = False

working_query = """
                SELECT a.id, a.body, a.owner_user_id
                FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` AS a
                INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` AS q
                    ON q.id = a.parent_id
                WHERE q.tags LIKE '%bigquery%'
                """
answers_query_job = client.query(working_query, job_config) 
answers_query_job.to_dataframe()
```

Second code,

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas

client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = client.dataset("stackoverflow", project="bigquery-public-data")
dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_ref)

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(maximum_bytes_billed=10**10)
job_config.use_query_cache = False


bad_query = """
                SELECT a.id, a.body, a.owner_user_id
                FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` AS a
                INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` AS q 
                    ON q.id = a.parent_id
                WHERE q.tags LIKE '%bigquery%'
                """

answers_query_job = client.query(working_query, job_config) 
answers_query_job.to_dataframe()
```

None of the above codes will work. They resulted with the error:

```
Query exceeded limit for bytes billed: 10000000000. 24460132352 or higher required.
```

On the other hand if `job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(maximum_bytes_billed=25000000000)` is set. Both queries run normally.

Comment: I want to have the cost controls enabled and don't see why a whitespace or whatever it is triggers this behaviour.

Comment: @glykocalyx, the query will process 23Gb of data  and will be billed more than 10**10 which is set as the maximum. For this reason, none of the queries will run. I have reproduced it using shell and none worked with this maximum set. On the other hand, If you set it to `bigquery.QueryJobConfig(maximum_bytes_billed=23000000000)` and comment `to_dataframe()`, both runs. They process the same amount of data, you can see that under the job details in the BigQuery UI.

Comment: The "working_query" will run nevertheless from kaggle notebook. Question is, why?

Comment: @glykocalyx, you probably have you cached results enable. So, you ran the query once, without the maximum limit set, then when u ran again the cached results were used. There is nothing to do with the extra space inside the query string. I have reproduced your case using shell and a Notebook within AI Platform, both queries work normally if you set the correct `total_bytes_billed`. I have updated my answer with more detailed explanation of my reproduction.

Comment: Unfortunately it has nothing to do with caching here. When I switch the query back and forth between the two working_query succeeds and bad_query gives the error message. Here I have a linked to the notebook with the problem if you would like to try yourself: [Notebook on kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/calyxus/bigquery-problem/edit)

Comment: @glykocalyx, I have updated the answer with my steps for reproduction.

Comment: thank you for your effort! Nevertheless I just added `UseQueryCache=False` to my QueryJobConfig and i still have the same behaviour.

Comment: @glykocalyx, have you increased the value to 25gb for the maximum bytes billed  in both queries ? I have used GCP to reproduce it, so if the issue persists with you, it is not related to BigQuery.

Comment: Might well be the kaggle notebook, I will look more in this direction.

Comment: @glykocalyx, I have found [this](https://www.kaggle.com/learn-forum/106403). Also, if the answer was useful, consider accepting and upvoting it. You can accept it clicking on the ✓ and upvote it clicking on the ▲.

Comment: Cannot upvote as my reputation is too low, but thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks again for your help, it was a cache problem as you have suggested! The queries have to be absolutely identical to retrieve data from cache, so even a whitespace matters here.